# salt state to run JSON API

Tags: json, salt-stack

I am quite new to SALT, I need to query a JSON API through slat state, may I know how best I should do. I am trying below is of no help though.

> Salt ‘*’ cmd.run  ‘curl --insecure -u "username:password" -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"action":"RouterName","method":"methodname","data":[{"limit":100000, "uid" : "Query UID"}],"tid":1}' https:///zport/dmd/device_router’

Can I use any state file to query JSON API of my application through SALT.

Comment: Is that an action? Do you want to use the output?

Comment: Yes thats an action. Yes I need to use ouput to trigger other actions.

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference between *module* and *state*.

**Modules**: Module runs the command/function every time and does not care if the task needs to be run or not. 
**State**: On the other hand, the state cares about the status of the task that needs to be executed. Based on the result, it decides if the task should be run or the system is in the desired *state* that the task wants it to be.

More about this issue *[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44453092/whats-the-big-difference-between-execution-modules-and-state-modules)*.

---

To *somehow* answer your question, you cannot be sure what is the state of a server that you are trying to curl from. That means, that you need to use a module to get the current output and decide upon that.